If $L$ is decidable, is the language of all substrings of $L$ decidable?
Let $L$ be a decidable language and consider the language $M$ of all substrings of any word in $L$.  It's easy to see that $M$ is recognizable by enumerating the words of $L$ and waiting to see if any of them contains the input $w$ as a substring.
I suspect that it is not decidable.  However, every example of an undecidable language that I know of, involves an input that is interpreted as the code of a Turing machine.  Since I don't think the "substring language" would help to decide such a language (and produce a contradiction), I'm not sure how to argue that such a language is undecidable.
I also can't think of how it could be co-recognizable either, since I can't think of a way that you could decide that a given input string is not a substring of any word in $L$.

Consider the set $S$ of all strings of the form "$\star\sigma\star\pi$" where $\sigma$ is a sentence in the language of arithmetic, $\pi$ is a (string representation of a) proof of $\sigma$ from the axioms of (first-order) Peano arithmetic, and $\star$ is a special character not used in the syntax of arithmetic or of proofs. This set is decidable, but its set of prefixes is not decidable; in particular, $\star\sigma\star$ is a substring of an element of $S$ iff $\sigma$ is a theorem of Peano arithmetic.
In particular, the set of substrings of elements of $S$ is c.e.-complete, so the obvious bound is in fact optimal.
